# How do I put single-quotes around string using Python csv writer?

Tags: python, file, csv, writer

```
with open("emails.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    for control_rent_email in control_group_renters:
        email_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,delimiter=',')
        email_writer.writerow([control_rent_email])
    csvfile.close()
```

I get the following output in the "emails.csv":

```
"susan@gmail.com"
"joe@gmail.com"
"sara@yahoo.com"
```

But I want the output to be

```
'susan@gmail.com',
'joe@gmail.com',
'sara@yahoo.com'
```

How do I put the correct parameters in csv.writer() to achieve this desired result?

UPDATE:

1)

```
email_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar=''', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,delimiter=',')                                                                                            
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

2) How do I place the "," to look like the output result?

Comment: You've used `quotechar='"'`  Why not `quotechar="'"`?

Comment: Python has more than one quoting style; you can use either `"'"`, or explicitly escape the quote with `'\''`.

Comment: See my answer. You didn't place the backslash.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything that gives a 'real' csv output using the csv.writer stuff. The 'hacky' way is to just write the emails to a file adding the necessary characters in the write statement. See my edit.

Comment: is there a way to quote a string outside csv module ?

Answer (score 3):

Change your quote characters as noted by others or use a backslash escape.

```
   email_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar='\'', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,delimiter=',')
```

We seemed to have missed your second problem:

This is a *hack* because I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the csv module. Rather than writing your files using the `csv.writer`, you can try it this way:

```
for control_rent_email in control_group_renters:
    csvfile.write('\'' + control_rent_email + '\'' + ',')
```

You also don't need to explicitly `close` the file you're writing to as the way you're opening it does it when it isn't referenced anymore.

I **hope** someone out there can figure out how to do this in a less-hack sort of way, particularly using the `csv.writer`. This way will suit your needs though.

Comment: This seems right. Given the OP's requirements, using the csv module seems to be the real hack.

Comment: @alexis So it's not just me then? I searched and tested for a bit to see if it *was* possible but I couldn't come up with a solution other than what I put above. I would think the `csv` module would have something that would do this easily.

Comment: The CSV module is for producing variants of the CSV format. Did you notice that (s)he doesn't want a comma after the last line? And why force the quotes around strings that don't need to be quoted, but have a trailing comma? That's not CSV. You can do it by using `QUOTE_NONE`, inserting the surrounding quotes by hand (as you did above), and passing an empty string to trigger a trailing comma (see my answer). Your solution is far more appropriate, as I said.

Answer (score 1):

A csv writer is a device you can use to write *multiple* lines into a file. You should only create one. Tell it to use a single quote as your quote character, and use it this way:

```
with open("emails.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    email_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,delimiter=',')
    for control_rent_email in control_group_renters:
        email_writer.writerow([control_rent_email])
```

I hope that you're giving a simplified example of what you really need; otherwise, why go to all this trouble when you're only printing one string per line? If you really want a trailing comma on each line *except the last,* you're really not aiming for any sort of CSV and you should construct your outputs directly.

That said, you can get trailing commas by passing an empty string to `writerow`, but only if you use `QUOTE_MINIMAL` or `QUOTE_NONE` (which will suppress the pointless quotes around the emails), instead of `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`; otherwise you'll get quotes around the empty strings.

```
email_writer.writerow([control_rent_email, ""])
```

For completeness, here's how you can *really* generate exactly the output you want, without the final comma and all:

```
with open("emails.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write( ",\n".join("'"+r+"'" for r in control_group_renters) +"\n" )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be your quotechar. Try:

```
with open("emails.csv", "w") as csvfile:
    for control_rent_email in control_group_renters:
        email_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC,delimiter=',')
        email_writer.writerow([control_rent_email])
    csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the quote character to `quotechar="'"`.

In your code you have explicitly specified that the quote character should be double quotes.

Comment: I think you meant explicitly set it to be a _single_ quote.

Comment: @martineau no, in the question the quote character is a single quote. That's why the quote character needs to be changed.